# Scrape basketball reference boxscores and output specific list elements to dataframe in R

Tags: r, rvest

I'm looking to scrape each of the boxscores for each game from basketball reference, as an example here:

https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202402220CHI.html

The tables are shown for different periods of the game, e.g. Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 and you can see these by clicking on the various options:

[image]

My goal is to get each of these tables (for EACH TEAM on EACH DAY of the season), join them together, then specify which period the table applies to, e.g. Q1, Q2, etc. most likely by adding a column that says "Q1", "Q2", etc.

My attempt so far:

```
    library(rvest)
    library(tidyverse)
    
    ##sample only - ultimately this will include all teams and all months and days
    
    month <- c('02')
    year <- c('2024')
    day <- c('220','270','280')   
    team <- c('CHI')

    make_url <- function(team, year, month, day) {
      paste0(
        'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/', year, month, day, team, '.html'
      )
    }
    
    dates <- expand.grid(
      team = team, year = year, month = month, day = day
    )
    
    urls <- dates |>
      mutate(
        url = make_url(team, year, month, day),
        team = team,
        date = paste(year, month, gsub('.{1}$', '', day), sep = '-'),
        .keep = 'unused'
      )
    
    
    scrape_table <- function(url) {
      page_html <- url %>%
        rvest::read_html()  
      
      page_html %>%
        rvest::html_nodes("table") %>%
        rvest::html_table(header = FALSE)
      
    }
    
    
    safe_scrape_table <- purrr::safely(scrape_table)
    
    tbl_scrape <- purrr::map(urls$url, \(url) {
      Sys.sleep(5)
      safe_scrape_table(url)
    }) |>
      set_names(paste(urls$team, urls$date, sep = '-'))
    
    
    final_result <- tbl_scrape |>
      purrr::transpose() |>
      pluck('result')
```

[image]

This is where I am stuck. I can see that `list[[1]]` and `list[[9]]` are the `Game` outputs, `list[[2]]` and `list[[10]]` are the `Q1` outputs, and so on.

How can I only get the ones that I need and bind them altogether? I only require Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4.

I also need to add a column that is effectively the title of each, e.g. 'CHI-2024-02-22' so I know which game these stats relate to.

Lastly, I am looking to add two columns, one for the home team and one for the away team. I know these details appear on each page, but I cannot figure out how to get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Inside the function "getPageTable", I read the game date and the table headings and all of the tables on the page.  I filter out only the box scores for the quarters 1, 2, 3, 4.  and remove the headings off the rows and then add on the game date and table heading onto the table and then merge into 1 data frame per game.
See the comments for additional details.

**Edited**

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

##sample only - ultimately this will include all teams and all months and days
month <- c('02')
year <- c('2024')
day <- c('220','270','280')   
team <- c('CHI')

make_url <- function(team, year, month, day) {
   paste0('https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/', year, month, day, team, '.html')
}

dates <- expand.grid(team = team, year = year, month = month, day = day)

urls <- dates |>
   mutate( url = make_url(team, year, month, day),
      team = team,
      date = paste(year, month, gsub('.{1}$', '', day), sep = '-'),
      .keep = 'unused'
   )

getPageTable <- function(url) {
   #read the page
   page <- read_html(url)

   #get the game's date
   gamedate <- page %>% html_element("div.scorebox_meta div") %>% html_text2()
   
   #get game title
   gameInfo <- page %>% html_elements("div.box h1") %>% html_text()
   #get the table headings
   headings <- page %>% html_elements("div.section_wrapper") %>% html_element("h2") %>% html_text()
   
   #find the quarter scores
   quarters <- grep("Q[1|2|3|4]", headings)
   
   #retrieve the tables from the page
   tables <- page %>% html_elements("div.section_wrapper") %>% html_element("table") 

   #select the desired headings and tables
   headings <- headings[quarters]
   tables <- tables[quarters] %>% html_table(header=FALSE)

   #add game date and team name/quater to the results
   tables <- lapply(1:length(tables), function(i) {
      #set column titles to second row
      names(tables[[i]]) <- tables[[i]][2,]
     tables[[i]] <- tables[[i]][-c(1:2),]  
      tables[[i]]$gamedate <- gamedate
      tables[[i]]$team <- headings[i]
      tables[[i]]$title <- gameInfo
      tables[[i]]
   })
   #merge the quarterly status into 1 dataframe
   df <- bind_rows(tables)
   df <- df %>% filter("Starters" != "Reserves"  | "Starters" != "Team Totals" )
   df
}


#loop through the URLS
dfs <- lapply(urls$url, getPageTable)
#merge into one big table
finalResult <- bind_rows(dfs)
finalResult <- finalResult %>% separate("team", into=c("team", "quarter"), " \\(")
finalResult$quarter <- sub("\\)", "", finalResult$quarter)
```

Comment: this looks great. I did get this warning message when looping through the URLs: The value argument of names<-() must be a character vector as of tibble 3.0.0. Also, the headers appear to be repeating a number of times in the final dataframe, can these be removed? And is it possible to split the `team` col into the team name and Q1, etc. AND add the opponent?

Comment: Also, if I add further dates, I get this error: `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.` I assume it is because no home games were played by that team on these days. How can this be avoided?

Comment: @Michael, made a couple of edits, should be closer to your final desired result.  This provides enough guidance to get you there.  As far as the 404 error, I suggest creating a new question and add the link to the page which is not working. (mostly likely a try/catch is needed here). There are several similar questions post here.

Comment: thanks @Dave2e were there any edits made? I still get the same output.

Comment: perfect @Dave2e thanks. I will explore the try/catch option.