# Avoid 404 error when scraping from multiple pages using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

This is a follow up to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78125023/scrape-basketball-reference-boxscores-and-output-specific-list-elements-to-dataf).

The code provided does give the desired output, however it seems there is an issue when a page does not exist, and I am trying to use try/catch to avoid these errors and continue.

For example, I am specifying all dates with the following:

```
month <- c('02')
year <- c('2024')
day <- c('220','270','280')   
team <- c('CHI')
```

This is fine, as Chicago played home games on all these days, hence the following urls all work:

https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202402220CHI.html

https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202402270CHI.html

https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202402280CHI.html

But if I add another day and/or month like so:

```
month <- c('02')
year <- c('2024')
day <- c(**'210'**,'220','270','280')   
team <- c('CHI')
```

Chicago did not play a home game on 21 Feb 24 and this url doesn't exist:

https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202402210CHI.html

I tried adding it to the code here:

```
page <- tryCatch(read_html(url), error = function(err) "error 404")
```

But then I received this message:

```
no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "character"
```

How can I skip the pages that don't exist and just return the values from those that do?

Full code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

##sample only - ultimately this will include all teams and all months and days
month <- c('02')
year <- c('2024')
day <- c('220','270','280')   
team <- c('CHI')

make_url <- function(team, year, month, day) {
   paste0('https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/', year, month, day, team, '.html')
}

dates <- expand.grid(team = team, year = year, month = month, day = day)

urls <- dates |>
   mutate( url = make_url(team, year, month, day),
      team = team,
      date = paste(year, month, gsub('.{1}$', '', day), sep = '-'),
      .keep = 'unused'
   )

getPageTable <- function(url) {
   #read the page
   page <- read_html(url)

   #get the game's date
   gamedate <- page %>% html_element("div.scorebox_meta div") %>% html_text2()
   
   #get game title
   gameInfo <- page %>% html_elements("div.box h1") %>% html_text()
   #get the table headings
   headings <- page %>% html_elements("div.section_wrapper") %>% html_element("h2") %>% html_text()
   
   #find the quarter scores
   quarters <- grep("Q[1|2|3|4]", headings)
   
   #retrieve the tables from the page
   tables <- page %>% html_elements("div.section_wrapper") %>% html_element("table") 

   #select the desired headings and tables
   headings <- headings[quarters]
   tables <- tables[quarters] %>% html_table(header=FALSE)

   #add game date and team name/quater to the results
   tables <- lapply(1:length(tables), function(i) {
      #set column titles to second row
      names(tables[[i]]) <- tables[[i]][2,]
     tables[[i]] <- tables[[i]][-c(1:2),]  
      tables[[i]]$gamedate <- gamedate
      tables[[i]]$team <- headings[i]
      tables[[i]]$title <- gameInfo
      tables[[i]]
   })
   #merge the quarterly status into 1 dataframe
   df <- bind_rows(tables)
   df <- df %>% filter("Starters" != "Reserves"  | "Starters" != "Team Totals" )
   df
}


#loop through the URLS
dfs <- lapply(urls$url, getPageTable)
#merge into one big table
finalResult <- bind_rows(dfs)
finalResult <- finalResult %>% separate("team", into=c("team", "quarter"), " \\(")
finalResult$quarter <- sub("\\)", "", finalResult$quarter)
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114066/using-trycatch-and-rvest-to-deal-with-404-and-other-crawling-errors

Comment: I have spent hours searching @Dave2e and have tried all of those. I can't work out what I am doing wrong. Everything returns this error: `no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: Try replacing the `read_html()` with `page <- tryCatch(read_html(url), error = function(err) "error 404")` and   `if (page[1] == "error 404") return()`

Comment: ok thanks @Dave2e. Does the `if (page[1] == "error 404") return()` go directly below the `page <- tryCatch(read_html(url), error = function(err) "error 404")`? I tried but couldn't get it to work. Are you able to edit the full code above so it is clear to me? It just returns an empty df in finalResult.

Comment: Also, in `dfs`, each list is `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. Wrap the call to `read_html` in `tryCatch` and return the error condition, if anything goes wrong. Then test the condition right after the read instruction. Like this you will have a list with both the data (URL's are OK) and the errors (URL's are not OK) and can test which are which outside the function.

Here is the function, corrected.

```
getPageTable <- function(url) {
  # read the page, returning the error condition if error 404 (or other)
  page <- tryCatch(
    read_html(url),
    error = function(e) e
  )
  if(inherits(page, "error")) {
    return(page)
  }
  # then continue as in the question's code 
  #get the game's date
  gamedate <- page %>% html_element("div.scorebox_meta div") %>% html_text2()
  
  #get game title
  gameInfo <- page %>% html_elements("div.box h1") %>% html_text()
  #get the table headings
  headings <- page %>% html_elements("div.section_wrapper") %>% html_element("h2") %>% html_text()
  
  #find the quarter scores
  quarters <- grep("Q[1|2|3|4]", headings)
  
  #retrieve the tables from the page
  tables <- page %>% html_elements("div.section_wrapper") %>% html_element("table") 
  
  #select the desired headings and tables
  headings <- headings[quarters]
  tables <- tables[quarters] %>% html_table(header=FALSE)
  
  #add game date and team name/quater to the results
  tables <- lapply(1:length(tables), function(i) {
    #set column titles to second row
    names(tables[[i]]) <- tables[[i]][2,]
    tables[[i]] <- tables[[i]][-c(1:2),]  
    tables[[i]]$gamedate <- gamedate
    tables[[i]]$team <- headings[i]
    tables[[i]]$title <- gameInfo
    tables[[i]]
  })
  #merge the quarterly status into 1 dataframe
  df <- bind_rows(tables)
  df <- df %>% filter("Starters" != "Reserves"  | "Starters" != "Team Totals" )
  df
}
```

---

Call the function above, check for valid return values and decide what to do with the errors. In the case below the bad URL's and the corresponding errors are printed as messages.

```
#loop through the URLS
dfs <- lapply(urls$url, getPageTable)
# get which weren't read in
err <- sapply(dfs, inherits, what = "error")
# optional, make a list of the bad ones
dfs_err <- dfs[err]
# and print the URL's and error messages
for(i in which(err)) {
  urls$url[i] %>% message()
  dfs_err[[i]] %>%
    conditionMessage() %>%
    message()
}

# these are the good ones and the rest of the code is like in the question
dfs <- dfs[!err]
#merge into one big table
finalResult <- bind_rows(dfs)
```

Comment: accepting this as it is clearly set out and I can see how the function is constructed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to try or catch anything if you check the status code of the response first.

```r
getPageTable <- function(url) {
   req <- httr::GET(url)
   if (req$status_code != 200) return(NULL)

   page <- read_html(req)
   ... continue as before
}
```

Comment: this is a very useful idea.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if your `tryCatch` returns a valid HTML object on error.

Example:

```
library(rvest)

## create sample urls, one faulty, one OK:
urls <- sprintf('https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202402%sCHI.html',
                c(210, 220)
)
```

```
# > urls |> cbind()
#      urls                                                              
# [1,] "https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202402210CHI.html"
# [2,] "https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202402220CHI.html"
```

upon error, return `minimal_html` with the error message wrapped in an HTML element you'll extract later on:

```
responses <- 
  urls |>
  Map(f = \(url) tryCatch(read_html(url),
                          error = \(e) sprintf('<div class="box"><h1>%s</h1></div>',
                                               e$message) |>
                                       minimal_html()
                          )
      )
```

digest response as desired (example):

```
responses |>
  Map(f = \(response) response |>
                      html_elements("div.box h1") |>
                      html_text()
      )
```

```
## + $`https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202402210CHI.html`
## [1] "HTTP error 404."
## 
## $`https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202402220CHI.html`
## [1] "Boston Celtics at Chicago Bulls Box Score, February 22, 2024"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of brute-forcing urls, you could collect those from https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2024_games.html :

```r
library(rvest)
url_ <- "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2024_games.html"
s <- session(url_)

month_links <- s |> 
  html_elements('.filter div a') |> 
  html_attr("href")

urls <- 
  lapply(month_links, \(lnk_) 
         session_jump_to(s, lnk_) |> 
           html_elements('table tbody td[data-stat="box_score_text"] a') |> 
           html_attr("href")
         ) |> unlist()
str(urls)
#>  chr [1:946] "/boxscores/202310240DEN.html" "/boxscores/202310240GSW.html" ...

# Feb 2024, CHI:
grep("202402.*CHI", urls, value = TRUE)
#> [1] "/boxscores/202402030CHI.html" "/boxscores/202402060CHI.html"
#> [3] "/boxscores/202402220CHI.html" "/boxscores/202402270CHI.html"
#> [5] "/boxscores/202402280CHI.html"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-09 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: very handy and I will definitely use this going forward.